# Crash STS when open with Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started

Tags: java, windows, sts

Hi this happend with version of Spring:

Spring Tool Suite 4

Version: 4.12.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 202109130635

The error in logs is:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini)

The file of log is in C:\Users\user\sts-4.12.0.RELEASE\configuration

Answer (score 0):

I think this version works with JDK  of Java only. So when I tried to open with a version 8  of Java STS inform me the exception. Changing to version of Java 11 in my laptop this works ok again.